# Connect to self-signed SSL website via Apache JMeter

Tags: ssl, jmeter

I try to do a performance test on a website that uses a self-signed SSL certificate.

My JMeter test plan works correct on a "usual" SSL site (with correctly signed certificate) and on the test page without SSL. As soon as I access the test page (using a self-signed cert) JMeter only creates errors. What I have tried:

1. Stored the certificate (via Browser) and imported it into Java (via Control Panel "Java")
2. Added the certificate to a keystore and started JMeter via the following commmand line (I have no other idea how to "reference the keystore in the JVM" in another way?!)

   > java -jar "ApacheJMeter.jar" -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore="C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\security\cacerts" -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=changeit

Thanks for hints how to get JMeter access the test page :)

The result (JMeter output) currently is:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor28.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPJavaImpl.readResponse(HTTPJavaImpl.java:264)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPJavaImpl.sample(HTTPJavaImpl.java:520)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:62)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1088)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1077)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:428)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:256)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getHeaderField(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLConnection.getHeaderFieldLong(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLConnection.getContentLengthLong(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLConnection.getContentLength(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getContentLength(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPJavaImpl.readResponse(HTTPJavaImpl.java:230)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
    ... 21 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this Answer: [JMeter and optional SSL client certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14607897/jmeter-and-optional-ssl-client-certificate#answer-14693655) Look at your port number in JMeter HTTP Request. Stadard port for https is 443.