# JMETER not recording a particular site

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Jmeter is not recording a particular site. However, it did record for the very first time, later something might have happened, below is the set up.

HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder > port 7878
Firefox > localhost (7878)

open firefox > start HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder and open WWW.xyzabc.com

Jmeter records perfectly as expected.

Now, after sometime i did the same, this time nothing is being recorded however, the site got opened on firefox.
Additionally, when i have stopped recording on jmeter, i was still able to open the site and perform actions on firefox, but for other sites i get "The proxy server is refusing connections"

Can anyone please explain this behaviour?

Comment: port:7878 is not the default port for proxy setting.Did you change the default setting?

Comment: This is not working, i am facing this issue for a specific site only (i am able to open the webpage but nothing is being recorded on jmeter), all the other sites are working fine.

Comment: try this out :
I have given here a recording tool info -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/50996226/5717031

Answer (score 1):

A couple of assumptions:

1. Your site uses HTTPS transport and Firefox isn't configured to record HTTPS traffic
2. Your site is running on your local machine and Firefox is configured to not to use proxy for local addresses.

In Firefox network configuration make sure:

- `Use this proxy server for all protocols` box is **checked**
- `No Proxy for:` input field is **empty**

[image: Firefox Proxy]

If it doesn't help you can try out the following:

1. Add the next line to *user.properties* file

   ```
   log_level.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy
   ```
2. Restart JMeter to pick the property up
3. Look for anything suspicious in *jmeter.log* file

If nothing help you can consider an alternative way of recording a JMeter test - [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732579-Chrome-Extension)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the step by step procedure to record a scenario in JMeter.
The easiest way to use recording is from **"Templates"** .

**Step1:** Open your **Firefox browser** and from **Network Connection settings** configure the **proxy server** as **HTTP Proxy: 127.0.0.1, Port: 8888**.
[See image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3Wp1.png)

**Step2:** Run your **Jmeter.bat** file and open **"Templates"** under File dropdown list and click **"Create"**.
[See image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyzPe.png)

**Step3:** Expand WorkBench and select **"HTTP(s) Test Script Recorder"**. And click **"Start"** at the bottom of the page.You will have two pop up to **Allow Firewall** and **Temporary Root CA Certification Installation**.Allow all those and now go to your browser and do your browser activity.When it's done **"Stop"** the **HTTP(s) Test Script Recorder**.

**Step4:** After this you will get the recorded script in JMeter with all your activity in the browser.It will automatically update under **Thread Group**.This script will contain all your page requests during browsing activity. [Sample script after recording is shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUzpH.png).

Comment: This is not working, i am facing this issue for a specific site only, all the other sites are working fine.

Answer (score -1):

If it's HTTPS, then you have to add its certificate to jmeter.

Comment: Could you please let me know how to add ?

Comment: Also, how did it run the first time? i'm confused.

Comment: Well, I am just guessing that website dev / owners have added ssl now for security reasons. If that is the case, go through below links.                             https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-set-your-jmeter-load-test-use-client-side-certificates   https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-https-traffic-jmeters-proxy-server  http://www.jajakarta.org/jmeter/1.7/en/user_manual/sslmanager.html  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14607897/jmeter-and-optional-ssl-client-certificate